# Exercise about operator defined as e exp ( selfadjoint operator)

Tags: linear-algebra, svd

in the context of svd and selfadjoints I am asked to solve this exercise.   I am not going to share my thoughts because they go nowhere. I would like some clue about this exercise. I have never seen e raised to an operator before.  Thanks in advance

$T:V \to V$  is a selfadjoint operator

There is another linear operator defined as $e^{T}: V \to V$ that has the following associated matrix in a basis named B.

$_{B}\left [ e^{T} \right ]_{B}=\begin{bmatrix}
e^{\lambda _{1}} & . & . & 0\\ 
. & e^{\lambda _{2}} & . &. \\ 
. & . & . &. \\ 
 0& . & . & e^{\lambda _{n}}
\end{bmatrix}$ being B the basis in which $_{B}\left [ T \right ]_{B}=\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda _1 & . & . & 0\\ 
. & \lambda _2 & . &. \\ 
. & . & . &. \\ 
 0& . & . & \lambda _n
\end{bmatrix}$

Prove with S and T selfadjoints operators such as TS=ST that $e^{T+S}=e^{T}\cdot e^{S}$

Comment: "I am not going to share my thoughts because they go nowhere": do not let that hold you back from sharing your thoughts. What does $_{B}\left [ \cdot \right ]_{B}$ mean?

Comment: I  know that both T and S can be diagonalized in the same basis, (simultaneous diagonalization ) so the diagonal representation of T+S has the sum of the eigenvalues ...

Comment: I suppose that you have a typo.  The final claim is : $e^{T+S}=e^{T}\cdot e^{S}$. Correct?

Comment: oh yes, thanks  you are right , I will change it now

Answer (score 0):

Given a linear operator $T$ the exponential operator is defined  via the absolutely convergent series (you can see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential)):
$$
e^T=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{T^n}{n!}
$$

and, if the operator is represented by a diagonal matrix (that is the matrix with the eigenvalues as diagonal elements in the basis of the corresponding eigenvectors), we can show that the exponential $e^T$ is represented, in the same basis, by a diagonal matrix with as diagonal elements the exponentials of the eigenvalues.

More: we can prove, using the usual proof for the exponents property $e^ae^b=e^{a+b}$, that if two linear operators $T,S$ commute, than $e^Te^S=e^Se^T=E^{T+S}$.

In your case the fact that the operators are self adjoint  ensure that  we have an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors in which the operators are represented by diagonal matrices.

Comment: I will try to  prove first  that $e^{T}$  is diagonal  in the same orthonormal eigenvectors  in which T is diagonal ( I hope my english is clear ) using the series for e^{x} that you suggest and that the powers of an operator conmute whithin each others.     Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

If $T$ , $S$  and $S+T$ verify your condition for  a same base $B$ of $V$ you have that

$e^T=Be^{D_T}B^{-1}$

$e^S=Be^{D_S}B^{-1}$

$e^{S+T}=Be^{D_{S+T}}B^{-1}$

where the matrix $e^{D_T}$ and $e^{D_S}$ are the matrix that you had written. 
Oviously $e^{D_{S+T}}=e^{D_S}e^{D_T}$ and so

$e^{S+T}=Be^{D_{S+T}}B^{-1}=Be^{D_S}e^{D_T}B^{-1}=$

$=Be^{D_S}B^{-1}Be^{D_T}B^{-1}=e^Se^T$

So I think that the condition $TS=ST$ can be used to get my hypothesis.

There is a more elegant way to define the exponential operator of a operator and in that way the proof of your statement is another.

Comment: The use of  $e^{D^{T}}$ is crystal clear ,  I think that the prove you wrote is the one that I was expected to be able to do.    In any case I need to think further about  this  "exponential operators of an operator" .   Thank you both !!  ( this forum is a great help to study )